# Is it a good to use 'IsBadCodePtr' to distinguish a given resource type?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm thinking about using [IsBadCodePtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366712(v=vs.85).aspx) to distinguish a [predefined resource type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009(v=vs.85).aspx) from a custom resource type name.

Is it good practice (or even the best method?) to use the `IsBadCodePtr` API to find out if a given resource type belongs to one of the predefined resource type or is there a better alternative?

Please note that I'm talking about resource type names and not IDs.

Comment: Note from the docs: *Important  This function is obsolete and should not be used. Despite its name, it does not guarantee that the pointer is valid or that the memory pointed to is safe to use. For more information, see Remarks on this page.* - this should be a good enough reason not to use it.

Comment: Well it might be for common purposes but it says nothing about Resources and it seems a good idea to use it. That's why I'm asking what could go wrong. I've read the docs.

Comment: @Benjamin: Resources are data, not code.  I don't know how you could say it seems a good idea to use a function designed for function pointers to test data pointers.

Comment: @BenVoigt To see if the resource type points to a valid address or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not good practice. You should instead use the [IS_INTRESOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro, which tells you if a resource pointer was created with `MAKEINTRESOURCE` (which means it isn't a real pointer). Note that this doesn't definitely mean it is "predefined", because you can call `MAKEINTRESOURCE` on your own resource IDs.

The `IsBad____Ptr` functions should not be used in general. As the documentation says:

> This function is obsolete and should not be used.

There is more information in this blog post by Microsoft's Raymond Chen: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I will use the the macro. I didn't even about it!